# xgboost error: not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, xgboost

I want to use XGBoost. When I try to execute code it always shows this error given below.

```
Exception has occurred: xgboost.core.XGBoostError
XGBoost Library (xgboost.dll) could not be loaded. Likely causes:   * OpenMP 
runtime is not installed (vcomp140.dll or libgomp-1.dll for Windows, 
libgomp.so for UNIX-like OSes)   * You are running 32-bit Python on a 64-bit 
OS Error message(s): ['[WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application'] 
File "G:\study\research\gbm\&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;", line 205, 
in _call_with_frames_removed
File "G:\study\research\gbm\&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap_external&gt;", 
line 678, in exec_module
File "G:\study\research\gbm\&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;", line 655, 
in _load_unlocked
File "G:\study\research\gbm\&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;", line 950, 
in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "G:\study\research\gbm\&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;", line 961, 
in _find_and_load
File "G:\study\research\gbm\&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;", line 205, 
in _call_with_frames_removed
File "G:\study\research\gbm\&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap_external&gt;", 
line 678, in exec_module
File "G:\study\research\gbm\&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;", line 655, 
in _load_unlocked
File "G:\study\research\gbm\&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;", line 950, 
in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "G:\study\research\gbm\&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;", line 961, 
in _find_and_load
File "G:\Study\Research\GBM\gbm.py", line 4, in <module>
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
```

I install xgboost, downloaded the dll file and installed it.

Comment: "You are running 32-bit Python on a 64-bit OS" could you check that you've installed 64bit python and xgboost?

Comment: yeah I checked that. It's 32 bit. What can I do now?

Comment: delet it and install the right version

Comment: which one python or xgboost?

Comment: python as said in the error

Comment: Yes. I solved that problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For me even though everything was on 64-bit I still got this error.

Finally I found **XGBoost requires Visual Studio 2017 C++ Redistributable installed in the windows machine.**.